# Jquery - Passing parameters to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass an ID to a function that turns it to a "flyout".

My base code is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="target_anchor1" href="#" title="XXXXXXXXXX">test 1</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#target_anchor1').flyout({
      title: '',
      content: function() {
        return document.getElementById('target_anchor1').title;
      },
      html: true,
      dismissible: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to do this dynamically, so I tried a function.
Function gets the parameter but does not create the flyout.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="target_anchor1" href="#" title="XXXXXXXXXX" onclick="anchorFlyout(this.id)">test 1</a>
<a id="target_anchor2" href="#" title="YYYYYYYYYY" onclick="anchorFlyout(this.id)">test 2</a>
<a id="target_anchor3" href="#" title="ZZZZZZZZZZ" onclick="anchorFlyout(this.id)">test 3</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function anchorFlyout(paramId) {
    alert(paramId);
    $('#' + paramId).flyout({
      title: '',
      content: function() {
        return document.getElementById(paramId).title;
      },
      html: true,
      dismissible: true
    });
  }
</script>
```

Code is taken from http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Customizable-Tooltip-Popover-Plugin-Flyout

Any idea?

Comment: your question makes very little sense

Comment: @Andrew what about now?

Comment: Are you sure "flyout" is a thing? Stack Exchange's error tells me it's not.

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/tooltip/Simple-Customizable-Tooltip-Popover-Plugin-Flyout.html

Answer (score 1):

Just make a regular function and have jquery statements in it:

```
function anchorFlyout(paramId) {
    $("#" + paramId).flyout({
        title: '',      
        content: function() {
            return document.getElementById(paramId).title;
        },
        html: true,
        dismissible: true
    });
};
anchorFlyout("target_anchor1")
```

Comment: tried this, but does not create the flyout. I have edited the code.

Comment: Well, you need to call the function: `anchorFlyout("target_anchor1")`

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I did that, check out the code above. I edited it.

Comment: Are you sure you did? I don't see any function callings. Edit: edited answer to show what I mean

Comment: I call it this way from the link --> onclick="anchorFlyout(this.id)"

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to be able to pass an ID to a function that turns it to a "flyout"?

```
function createFlyout(elementID) {
    $("#"+elementID).flyout({
        title: '',      
        content: function() {
            return document.getElementById(elementID).title;
        },
        html: true,
        dismissible: true
    });
}
```

---

**Or you could use a custom JQuery function...**

```
$.fn.createFlyout = function() {

    this.flyout({
        title: '',      
        content: function() {
            return this.attr("title");
        },
        html: true,
        dismissible: true
    });

    return this;
}
```

```
$("#myDiv").createFlyout();
```

Comment: I want to pass an ID to a function that turns it to a "flyout". I didn't know how to explain it, sorry. I tried first suggestion (being honest, didn't understand how to use second one you told me.) So, I edited the post. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The second function is a jQuery custom function, and you'd call it just like you would call flyout. Instead of doing `$(element).flyout( ... )`, you could just do `$(element).createFlyout();` In regards to the first function not working, are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: Your first function has `return document.getElementById('#'+paramId).title;`. It should *not* have a `#`, as `getElementById` is a native JS function: `return document.getElementById(paramId).title;`

Comment: I updated the code. I deleted the #. Got no errors in console. Function gets the param (the alert inside the function works) but it seems it is not "entering" here --> $('#'+paramId).flyout({ ....